# 64Bit Java 8 on Windows Server 2008 uses more or less whole server CPU

Tags: java, oracle, jvm, 64-bit, heap-memory

We have experienced situations when moving from 32Bit (oracle 8u33) to 64Bit (oracle 8u66 also 102) periods where a single java process uses all 16 cores of the machine or >50% for longer durations 5-15 minutes after start. our log indicates a period with lots of I/O (i.e. writing via hibernate to MySQL) is stretched due to the bad performance over that longer peririod. cpu goes back to known low values once the outgoing write frequency goes down.

We have not seen such extreme cpu usage ever before. our application is rather I/O, than CPU resource intensive. it needs typically far less than one core. we run it on windows servers for about 6 years already.

my assumption is that when heap gets tight (same xmx settings used for the 64bit version), the jvm tries at all cpu cost to avoid a "out of heap" situation:

- visual vm shows the high cpu (mainly it's not GC related CPU!) when heap usage reaches a "ceiling" at about 70MB below the configured max size.
- indeed, after increasing the heap size -> the high cpu symptom is gone.

while I know the workaround, I target two things with my entry here:

- can someone confirm the assumption?
- learn more what the jvm is doing and why - is it v8/64Bit/windows specific?
- how to tune the jvm behavior to not impact the other processes (we have >50 instances on a server), but rather give up, run out of mem and die (we have availability monitoring in place and could follow up)?

thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like in fact you're memory bound, and your heap limit is too low for your working set.

Comment: This could happen if you don't increase the heap size esp if you are close to the limit already. I suggest you make the maximum 3x the working size if you want to minimise overhead. Perhaps as your machine is pretty old you are limited in memory usage.  Note: a typical server these days is 32 GB - 128 GB of memory and leaving a few GB of head room is not usual.

Comment: Those are several unrelated questions in my opinion. One is about how to solve a resource exhaustion issue of *one* JVM and the other is how to coordinate the resource consumption of multiple JVMs on one machine. You should ask them separately.

Comment: @Peter: we have lots of mem and increased heap for part of the instances already.

Comment: @the8472 the original question was answered, since nobody seems to considered CPU behavior unnormal. the other question then, how to make the jvm default settings "less egoistic" seems now obvious: tune GC to use only once core max (and see). we can afford a few seconds pause without pb. lucky us :)

Comment: @einsatzmaenner I would increase the minimum and maximum heap until you don't see an improvement in performance, or just make it large e.g. 32 GB and monitor it to see how much was really used and reduce it.

Answer (score 1):

What we had seen was "normal" when a 64bit jvm runs out of memory.
By default it will very aggressively run GC with so many parallel threads that the whole server suffers.

Since we have many jvms running we don't want to have impact on all the other at memory shortage on one of them. The solution was to use single threaded gc: `-XX:+UseSerialGC` (and to limit the metaspace as well `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m`). Since then - about a year ago - jvms behave well. 
The default setting of a jvm seems to be tuned for being alone on a server

Answer (score 0):

> (same xmx settings used for the 64bit version)

The internal structures used by jvm on 64bits will consume more memory than for 32 bits (struct alignment and pointer sizes if nothing else) - keeping the same max heap size (-Xmx) is asking for troubles.

After some digging:

- [some reported](https://plumbr.eu/blog/java/should-i-use-32-or-64-bit-jvm) "30-50% of more heap is required on 64-bit" along with "Longer garbage collection pauses."
- sorry that's for java5 <sup><sub><strike>Oracle's FAQ [mentions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_pause) the need of tuning down the -Xmx from excessive values and the use of `-Xincgc` to avoid those long CG times</strike></sub></sup>
- [Java 8 GC tuning here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/)

Comment: I had a look to the java GC tuning link. it describes the paradigm of rather spending CPU than allowing longer pause. also from reading it makes me feel the overhead must be big before an out of memory situation occurs. Jconsole shows the PS Mark Sweep GC is used. It doesn't explain why much more than the typical quarter of the cores is busy (here the whole box). To me it feels as if the (sys?)calls burn lots of cpu, not the GC itself, at least the graphs in the visualvm imply that.  I set now -XX:+UseSerialGC with reduced heap and will see.

Comment: your answer contains misinformation. a) internal JVM structures are *not* part of the java object heap b) on 64bit JVMs with max heap size < 32GB compressed pointers are used by default, making them no larger than they are on 32bit builds.

Comment: @the8472 to use a meme... [citation needed] I'm happy to stand corrected, but if a correction is to be made, then provide the source the same way I did.